# Sql server, php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have an application in php with a database in sql server. When I want to show the result of a query I see a white page.
This is the code:

```
        $myServer = "ip of my server";
        $myUser = "username";
        $myPass = "usernamepassword";
        $myDB = "name of db"; 
    //connection to the database
        $dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
            or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
    //select a database to work with
        $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
            or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 
    //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
        $query = "SELECT DAT, ORA_INI, ORA_FIN, DES, RIU ";
        $query .= "FROM dbo.bacheca ";
    //execute the SQL query and return records
        $result = mssql_query($query)
            or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());
    //Show results in table
    $o = '<table id="myTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            </tr>
            </thead><tbody>';

               while ( $record = mssql_fetch_array($result) )
          {
              $o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['DAT'].'</td><td>'.$record ['RIU'].'</td></tr>';
          }              

            $o .= '</tbody></table>';

            echo $o;
            //free result set memory
        mssql_free_result($result);
    //close the connection
        mssql_close($dbhandle);
```

anyone can help me?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: `mysql_error()` will not work with MSSQL

Comment: `mysql_error()` needs to be replaced with `mssql_get_last_message()` on line 16

Comment: Side note, PHP is like, the worst language yeah? Every PHP post is a half dozen comments discussing which deprecated function should not be used. Then another half dozen on how to prevent injection.

Comment: Sorry but is the first time that I work with sql server and I find this code on this link (http://forum.html.it/forum/showthread/t-990799.html).
Anytime I have changed the code and I see a Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in G:\xampp\htdocs\confindustria\eventi.php on line 9

Comment: @JacobH PHP is good in the hands of a good developer. For those learning (due to the number of outdated tutorials out there) they need the warnings about deprecated functions so they can start on a good foot right out of the gate.

Comment: If you're getting a call to undefined function it means the MSSQL drivers are not installed, so PHP needs to be compiled with those installed.

Comment: Yes @JayBlanchard thank's I've solved with installation of mssql drivers on my xampp.